# Java: string to ImageIcon?

Tags: java, imageicon

Is there anyway to convert a String to an ImageIcon?

Sort of like the code here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Createaniconinmemory.htm

Instead of the red rectangle, I would like to display a String as ImageIcon.

My intention is to display this dynamically created ImageIcon besides the Jtree nodes.

Comment: Why not get the renderer of the tree to render the `String`?  I don't see the need for making it an icon (at any point).

Comment: is it possible to replace the imageicon of each tree node with a string? This could work for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `drawString` on `Graphics2D` object to draw the string to a graphic. Then, its straightforward to build an ImageIcon using the `Graphics2D` object. For more details on how to draw a string to graphics, look [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Converting-text-to-image-in-java-awt-339.php).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dynamic Icon, like this:

```
public class DynamicIcon implements Icon
{
  Font                     font         = new Font( "SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12 );
  private final static int DEFAULT_SIZE = 16;
  private int              width        = DEFAULT_SIZE;
  private int              height       = DEFAULT_SIZE;

  private String           iconText;

  public DynamicIcon( String iconText )
  {
    this.iconText = iconText;

    recalculateIconWidth( iconText );
  }

  private void recalculateIconWidth( String iconText )
  {
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext( null, true, true );
    Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds( iconText, frc );
    width = (int) bounds.getWidth();
    height = (int) bounds.getHeight();
  }

  @Override
  public int getIconHeight()
  {
    return height;
  }

  @Override
  public int getIconWidth()
  {
    return width;
  }

  @Override
  public void paintIcon( Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y )
  {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setFont( font );

    g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );
    g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

    //FontColor
    g2d.setPaint( Color.BLACK );
    g2d.drawString( iconText, 4, 12 );
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I make it so that the font gets resized to fill the button it is in?